# Getting empty result from Alpaca crypto data API

Tags: python

I am trying Alpaca API to get ETHUSD last trade price using Python SDK right now and puzzled why I'm getting empty result.

```
import alpaca_trade_api

api = alpaca_trade_api.REST()
api.get_trades("ETHUSD", "2022-03-08", "2022-03-08", limit=10).df
```

response is: `[]`

Do I need to set the exchange somehow in the query?
I have the free tier market api

Comment: Your code should be fully functional with private stuff like keys hidden.  It is impossible to know what is going on with just one line.

Comment: better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run.

Comment: Will update accordingly

Comment: The code snippet is updated to reproduce it

Answer (score 2):

https://alpaca.markets/learn/crypto-api-guides/getting-started-with-alpaca-crypto-api/

the function should be get_crypto_trades

trade_data = alpaca.get_crypto_trades('BTCUSD', "2021-06-08", "2021-06-09").df